# use "as vi.Mock" for methods from a mocked element when using typescript

Tags: typescript, mocking, vuejs3, vitest

When I mock vue-router with Jest, and want to mock the return value of an internal method, typescript doesn't understand that the inner method has become a mock, and can be treated as such.

For exapmle:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
jest.mock('vue-router');
useRoute .mockReturnValue({
```

That won't work. So the trick is to instruct typescript to treat it as a mock

```
const useRouteNew = useRoute as jest.Mock;
useRouteNew.mockReturnValue({
```

So with Jest that works, but I'm trying to imitate that with Vitest:

```
import { vi } from "vitest";
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
vi.mock('vue-router');
const useRouteNew = useRoute as vi.Mock;
useRouteNew.mockReturnValue({
```

That deosn't work. Here typescript complains that it "can't find the 'vi' namespace"

Any idea what I can do here with Vitest to get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vi` import from `'vitest'` is not a namespace, it's a const alias of a class (`VitestUtils`), which doesn't contain any types or interfaces.

All Vitest interfaces and types, including `Mock`, are exported by `'vitest'` directly:

```
import { vi, Mock } from 'vitest'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
vi.mock('vue-router')
const mockedUseRoute = useRoute as Mock
//...
```